# how to separate the elements present in NSMutable array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an application with `NSMutablearray` that displays as follows.I want another array which contains all cities one after another and without NO CITY. As of now, the object at index 1 shows :

```
 2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] cities Array (
                                            "Bangalore",
                                            "Chennai",
                                            "Delhi",
                                            "Mumbai"
                                            )
```

I want this to be separated as :

```
Bangalore
Chennai
Delhi
Mumbai
Pune with out NO CITY


2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] cities Array  NO CITY
2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] cities Array (
"Bangalore",
"Chennai",
"Delhi",
"Mumbai"
)
2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] functionalities Array NO CITY
2014-02-07 18:41:15.568 [313:a0b] functionalities Array Pune
```

Comment: What is the requirement

Comment: Please check my answer...it will work

Comment: I'm getting my NSMutablearray like array of array.The values i'm getting are dynamic.So in my array object at index gives this entire thing 2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] cities Array (
                                            "Bangalore",
                                            "Chennai",
                                            "Delhi",
                                            "Mumbai"
                                            )
I want to these cities in separated index,followed by other objects.

Comment: You want your array to be added in some other array ?.is it so ?

Comment: Can we have a chat ?..give me ur id ? i will surely help u

Comment: My array is array of array.I want to seperate the inside array elements so that at each index only one element is present.This is what i'm getting: 2014-02-07 18:41:15.567 [313:a0b] cities Array ( "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai" ) But i want these cities to be separated and i want array which shows like this:2014-02-07 18:41:15.568 [313:a0b] functionalities Array Bangalore.2014-02-07 18:41:15.568 [313:a0b] functionalities Array Chennai.2014-02-07 18:41:15.568 [313:a0b] functionalities Array Delhi.2014-02-07 18:41:15.568 [313:a0b] functionalities Array Mumbai

Comment: I am not getting your requirement as you are saying something different now

Comment: I want the array inside an array to be seperated

Comment: sorry. not getting requirement

Comment: you can create array on runtime and separate them

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution :

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bangalore",@"Chennai", @"Delhi", @"Pune", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", [arr description]);

    NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *str in arr) {
        if (![str isEqualToString:@"Pune"]) {
            [arr1 insertObject:str atIndex:arr1.count];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 description]);
```

If, you want to do in same array, use the following code :

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:@"Banagalore"];
    [arr addObject:@"Delhi"];
    [arr addObject:@"Mumbai"];
    [arr addObject:@"Pune"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [arr description]);

    for (int i = 0; i <[arr count] ; i++ )
    {
        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Pune"]) {
            [arr removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [arr description]);
```